# C# AES encryption / decryption returning incorrect result

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, aes

I've created a simple AES encryption / decryption service based on the MSDN example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is my code with a calling function and a hard coded key for the test:

```
public class AesEncryptionService
{
    private const int InitializationVectorLength = 16;
    private static readonly byte[] Key = Convert.FromBase64String("W+jcxfBJm37AAZujiktg4qCdy3k8D+vIrj4exFxFpIY=");

    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] input)
    {
        using (var aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.Key = Key;

            Console.WriteLine("Key: " + Convert.ToBase64String(aes.Key));
            Console.WriteLine("IV: " + Convert.ToBase64String(aes.IV));
            Console.WriteLine("Input: " + Convert.ToBase64String(input));

            using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor())
                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(outputStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(input);
                }

                var output = outputStream.ToArray();
                Console.WriteLine("Output: " + Convert.ToBase64String(output));

                var encrypted = aes.IV.Concat(output).ToArray();
                return encrypted;
            }
        }
    }

    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] input)
    {
        var initializationVector = input.Take(InitializationVectorLength).ToArray();
        input = input.Skip(InitializationVectorLength).ToArray();

        using (var aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.Key = Key;
            aes.IV = initializationVector;

            Console.WriteLine("Key: " + Convert.ToBase64String(aes.Key));
            Console.WriteLine("IV: " + Convert.ToBase64String(aes.IV));
            Console.WriteLine("Input: " + Convert.ToBase64String(input));

            using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor())
                using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(input))
                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(inputStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    cryptoStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
                }

                var output = outputStream.ToArray();
                Console.WriteLine("Output: " + Convert.ToBase64String(output));

                return output;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var encryptionService = new AesEncryptionService();
        var input = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();

        Console.WriteLine("Encrypting...");
        var encrypted = encryptionService.Encrypt(input);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Decrypting...");
        var decrypted = encryptionService.Decrypt(encrypted);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Input: " + Convert.ToBase64String(input));
        Console.WriteLine("Output: " + Convert.ToBase64String(decrypted));
    }
}
```

And this is an example of the output I get:

```
Encrypting...
Key: W+jcxfBJm37AAZujiktg4qCdy3k8D+vIrj4exFxFpIY=
IV: 7tb1BwOOcCdH/h1wdUmrtw==
Input: UsyLMdqbuUC5cVW/+p6vWA==
Output: 4KAhNOwNiNpmPxjvvx38cA==

Decrypting...
Key: W+jcxfBJm37AAZujiktg4qCdy3k8D+vIrj4exFxFpIY=
IV: 7tb1BwOOcCdH/h1wdUmrtw==
Input: 4KAhNOwNiNpmPxjvvx38cA==
Output: U3lzdGVtLkJ5dGVbXQ==

Input: UsyLMdqbuUC5cVW/+p6vWA==
Output: U3lzdGVtLkJ5dGVbXQ==
```

As you can see, the decrypted output does not match the input. I must have make a mistake in the code somewhere but I can't seem to spot it... can anyone help?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks to me like you are putting the IV at the end in the Encrypt phase, then pulling the beginning off for the IV in the Decrypt phase.  I never used the .Take method so I don't know for sure.  Could it be this though?

Comment: Nope, I'm putting the IV at the front in the encryption phase. You can see in the example output that the IVs match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft's example uses `StreamWriter`, which works with `string`. You work with `byte[]`, but still use `StreamWriter`, and its overloaded member `Write(object)` that internally calls `ToString()` on the object. When you call `ToString()` on `byte[]` you always get "System.Byte[]" as a string. 13 bytes, just as the final result has. Actually, if in the last line you replace

```
Console.WriteLine("Output: " + Convert.ToBase64String(decrypted));
```

with

```
Console.WriteLine("Output: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted));
```

that's exactly the string you'd see.

You should use `BinaryWriter` instead of `StreamWriter`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I can't believe I didn't spot that I was always getting exactly the same output no matter what the random input was!